# Binding onScrolling listener to the android ListView

Tags: android, listview

just wanted to ask is there a possibility to bind some listener to the ListView scroll event.

What I would like to achieve is that once ListView have been scrolled to the bottom I would like to ask server for more data if any is there.

I know that there is a function like: getLastVisiblePosition() but I assume it must bu used in some kind of listener in order to compare with currently last visible position, am I right ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just to extrapolate on TomTo's answer, some thoughts on how you might do this (theoretical, I haven't tried this in practice):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //Check if the last view is visible
        if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount) {
            //load more content
        }
    }
});
```

Since `firstVisibleItem` is returns an index (0-based), I increment by one to get the actual item number. Then, if that, plus the number of visible items, is greater than the total number of items, then in theory the last view should be visible. Shouldn't be a problem, but keep in mind this isn't called till the scrolling is finished.

Comment: I will have a look in a min and let you know

Comment: ok so it should be something like: if (view.getLastVisiblePosition()+1 == NUMBER_OF_RESULTS) {} instead your IF, but good hint anyway, thanks

Comment: Heh, didn't even think about getLastVisiblePosition. Much simpler. :) Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

used

`if (++visibleItemCount > totalItemCount)`

instead

`if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount)`

Answer (score 0):

[AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29) ?