# Android - ListView event when user reaches 50º list item

Tags: android, events, listview, listener

I want to set a simple listener in a ListView so when the user passes through the 50º item of the list, I call a thread that will append 100 more items into that list.

I am looking for an event to do that for over an hour now and I don't seem to be able to find one. There are tons of events for when a list item will be clicked or something like that, but I can't find one for when the user simples passes through the item in the scroll processing.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ScrollListener on list view, when it reaches end of the list u will get the last item, then add the progressbar at the footer and then start thread where u can load the other items, and notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter , and you will get the list with added items..!!

And you can check whether the item number  50 is reached, in onScroll().

Comment: Your answer made me go to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432931/binding-onscrolling-listener-to-the-android-listview

I found the solution there. It worked here. However, is there any way to add new items without calling  notifyDataSetChanged() ??? I think calling this method makes the whole list to be reload again (not just the new items added).

Comment: yeah it will do that , i know but there is a method from where you can set the selection of focus on list view,(so you can set the selection on which item you want to focus) method name is setSelection(int position), so you can do it now i think even after calling notifyDatasetchanged()...!! So list will be loaded but you will get focus on last item from where data set changed..hope you got the idea...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to do this, because the `ListView` recycles the item views. So you dont occupy memory for the listview items (per each value), you just use memory for the `ArrayList`(or any data type you use for feeding).

Also you can do this whenever user reaches the end of the listview (last listview item) then refeed the adapter with the new value and then call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

About reaching 50% of listview visible items can make things scrambled because you'll always have the 50% reached, otherwise you can improvise (reaching 50% on the ArrayList instead ListView) by checking if more than 50% of the existing ArrayList is displayed, let's say you 10 items and the 6th item is on the listview count / 2, you check if the on that half listview item is more than 50% of data feed for the listview you  feed with new data. (I might be unclear)

I hope the idea will help you.

Comment: Hi Nikola. Thank you for the quickly reply! I am aware of the notifyDataSetChanged() method, however, my problem is how do I set the event for when the last item list is shown (when the user reaches the bottom of the list, but don't click in any list item). Is there any event there? My main reason to do that is because there is too much data to load into the ArrayList, and I don't want to load them all at first. I want to load 50, and then, when the user reaches the end, loads 50 more (that is, put 50 more items into the ArrayList and then call .notifyDataSetChanged() and so on).

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such event listener, but you can create either `interface` for that, or do some testing in the `getView()` if the adapter reached the end of ArrayList and then add more elements...I hope this is reasonable.

Comment: Your idea of putting the code into the getView() method seems great! However, I found another solution (the event that I was looking for) in the avove answer. I'm just wondering if there is a way to draw the new item lines without having to call the notifyDataSetChanged() method now... But thanks for helping Nikola!

Comment: Nope, .notifyDatasetChanged() redraws the listview with new values.