# Android - How to set maximum size for listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to make a listview with dynamic size. When I press the button, it will add a row to the listview. And I want the button is always aligned to bottom of the list view.

The problem is listview will push the button out of screen when it have enough rows. So in this case, how to make the button align to bottom of the screen or set the max height for the listview? But when the listview just have 1 or 2 rows, I want the button is right below the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, you have to dynamically change the position of your button. From my comment, this is the answer.

1. Attach listener to your ListView : see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4433294/1377145
2. In the listener callback, check the visibility of your button :

`Rect videoBounds = new Rect();
yourButton.getGlobalVisibleRect(videoBounds);`

`getGlobalVisibleRect` will return true if the button is visible > 0%, false either.

3. To fix button on the bottom : change the LayoutParams of your button and set `alignParentButtom` to true. Else set `alignParentButtom`to false.

***bis :*** depending on your layout, you will have to "move" your button in the view tree with removeView/addView. Don't forget to removeview so the view will not have a parent naymore before adding it to another view.

**Additional note :** to have a % visibility on your button, you can use the `videoBounds.height()` and a rule of three :

```
100 * videoBounds.height() / yourButton.getHeight
```

*EDIT : change answer to match accepted one.*

Comment: I just want the button align to bottom screen when the listview push it out side. If the listview just have 1-2 rows, the button have to right below the listview

Comment: You have to attach a listener to the listview onScroll, checking if the visibility of your button is less than 100%, get parent from your button and removeView(yourButton) and add your button to the correct view and change LayoutParams to match alignParentButtom

Comment: Dear Hugo, thanks for your help.
But how to check visibility percent of a view.

Comment: `Rect videoBounds = new Rect();
yourButton.getGlobalVisibleRect(videoBounds);` getGlobalVisibleRect will return true if visible > 0%, false either. 

Additionaly, you can checj the height of `videoBounds.height()` and compare it with your button height to know exactly how much the button is visible. Let me know is it's working for you, I will edit the answer right after

Comment: Dear Hugo, it seem be ok. But I will check it tomorrow because now is 12AM and I had a busy day. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Hugo, it works very well. Like you say, I put a nav view right below the button. Then I check the availability of the nav view when the listview is added a new row. If it is invisible, it mean be nav view was pushed out of the view. So set layout again for the list view. That's exactly what I need. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Hugo. Is there a problem. I try to get percent visibility of the button. But the button.getHeight() and the bound.height() are always the same.

Comment: Will change the answer tomorrow with the percent issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to be displayed even though the user is at the top of the list view see other answers, but if you prefer to display the button when the user scrolls to the bottom of the listView use this approach with a footer.

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

The footer layout contains the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can have into Linear Layout a ListView and a button with different weight. Something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/reportCommentsLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/reportCommentsListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    </ListView>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reportCommnets_Addbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="Button" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a RelativeLayout with the Button using the rule alignParentBottom=true and the ListView using the rule above. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/button" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Add"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/add"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to inject my own personal opinions, but I think a "add more" or :load more button" always be the last view within a ListView.

To answer your question, to achieve what you need, the Listview and the "add row" button should be siblings within a ViewGroup.

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

The key point here is that the Button has a fixed height and the ListView takes the rest of the space. The button also aligns to the bottom of the parent view.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I mean the priority of the button:

1 - Below the listview, if it have space.

2 - Align bottom of the screen, if the listview pushed it out side.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout. 
Put the button at the bottom of screen, and set the listView position above him:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is ok. But when the listview just have 1 or 2 row, I want the button is right below the listview. Your solution make the button always align at bottom.